# Does Gnosis manage the hosting of Safe Apps?

Tags: gnosis-safe

When a new safe app is released, can a code snapshot be taken and served by Gnosis or does it have to be an HTML embed served by the app creator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safe team stores a URL to the app and embeds it as an iframe